# React props not loading fast enough

Tags: reactjs, react-props, use-effect

I am trying to useEffect to set the latitude and longitude of a map when a component loads. The problem is that the component loads and renders before the props are added to the useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props.bandLocation)
    // If I run this with a setTimeout it returns the data... but without the setTimeout it is an empty array. I need to set the latitude and longitude below to the data passed in through props... 
    setViewport({
        latitude: props.bandLocation[0],
        longitude: props.bandLocation[1],
        width: '100%',
        height: '200px',
        zoom: 2,
    })
}, [])
```

Answer (score 2):

Destructure `props` and add dependencies to the effect:

```
const { bandLocation } = props
useEffect(() => {
    setViewport({
        latitude: bandLocation[0],
        longitude: bandLocation[1],
        width: '100%',
        height: '200px',
        zoom: 2,
    })
}, [bandLocation])
```

This way, the effect will run only when `bandLocation` changes.

Comment: Thanks! Is there an advantage to Destructuring vs just putting props in the dependencies like the example above?

Comment: Yes. React will complain anytime you put `props` in the deps array. Only put the bare minimum dependencies to reduce the number of times the effect is ran.

Comment: Awesome! So simple. I have been screwing with this for like an hour and a half. Thanks so much -

Answer (score 0):

Set useEffect dependency to `props` so that when the props change the component re-renders accordingly. like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props.bandLocation)
    // If I run this with a setTimeout it returns the data... but without the setTimeout it is an empty array. I need to set the latitude and longitude below to the data passed in through props... 
    setViewport({
        latitude: props.bandLocation[0],
        longitude: props.bandLocation[1],
        width: '100%',
        height: '200px',
        zoom: 2,
    })
}, [props])
```

To further explain this the useEffect you currently have isn't aware of its surroundings so to say, as in it runs on component mount but then it doesn't care what happens. When you add props as a dependency, not only does it run the first time it also keeps a watch on changes to the props and then runs again whenever it detects changes.